# Perl variable scopes seemingly not cooperating

Tags: perl, scope

All my variables are declared following `my $var` format.

In my program I call `mainMethod()`

Then in `mainMethod` I define a DateTime variable and then pass it to a separate helper method 3 times.:

```
 my ($day,$month,$year)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
 my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year      => $year,
    month     => 2 + $month,
    day       => 1,
    hour      => 8,
    minute    => 30,
    time_zone => 'America/New_York'
);
helper($dt, $year, $month, $day,);
helper($dt,$year, $month, $day,);
helper($dt,$year, $month, $day,);
```

In `helper` I start with:

```
my $date = $_[0];
my ($year, $month, $day) = ($_[1],$_[2],$_[3]);
```

This method does a lot of different things but the only changes I make to `$date` is `$date = $date->add(days => (3 - $date->day_of_week) % 7);`

The problem is, it seems like the changes I make `$date` in my helper method, persist through each time I call the method from `mainMethod` Note: I'm not returning anything

For example, if `$dt` was instead `5` and `helper` was `$date + 2` I would get

```
helper($dt) #output: 7
helper($dt) #output: 9
helper($dt) #output: 11
```

Instead of the expected 5 for every response.

Is there some step that I'm missing to reset those variables at the end of the method?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of what `helper()` does, as well as the values for `$year` and `$month`.

Comment: Solution: `$date = $date->clone->add(days => (3 - $date->day_of_week) % 7);`

Comment: **Tip:** in _helper_ you could use `my($date,$year,$month,$day) = @_;` to avoid extra typing.

Comment: This is the danger of mutable state, and the benefit of immutable APIs like [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` creates a [reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

So when you call `helper($dt)` you pass a copy of the reference to `helper`. It doesn't create a whole new DateTime object.

Any changes you make to the value you pass are made to the single DateTime object you have already created.

If you want to create three different DateTime objects, then you need to call `DateTime->new` three times.

Comment: That is a little bit frustrating, but makes sense. Looks like I can use `$dt->clone()` to set `$date` and that seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with scoping. Your DateTime object is a reference. That's how objects work in Perl.

To explain what's going on, I will use a simpler data structure. An array reference works just the same way.

```
my $foo = [];

helper($foo);
print "@$foo\n";

helper($foo);
print "@$foo\n";

helper($foo);
print "@$foo\n";

sub helper {
    my $bar = $_[0];
    push @$bar, 1;
}
```

The output of this program will be

```
1
1 1
1 1 1
```

Just like with your DateTime object, we're passing a reference to the `helper()` function. Passing a scalar value like this creates a copy, but because the variable only contains a reference to somewhere else in memory, it copies that *pointer*. It will still point at the same place in memory, so any changes you make to that will be reflected in your original DateTime object.

Comment: a great example

Comment: "That's how objects work". That's how references work, not objects.

Comment: @SpiceMan Maybe that part is unclear. Objects in Perl are always references. Not always hash references, but they're always references. So you never get a copy of the object when you pass it to another function.

Comment: Even your code is an example with an unblessed arrayref. Not all references are objects. You say "this is how objects work" and show an arrayref in your snippet. I would change that to "this is how references work (and objects are references to blessed stuff)" or something.

Comment: @SpiceMan I have to disagree I'm afraid. I am saying _that_ (the behaviour that OP mistakenly attributed to scoping) is the way objects work. And the fact that objects always are references is how objects work in Perl. `bless` doesn't matter for my example.

Comment: Just a bit of pedantry: objects in Perl are always accessed through references, but the referent is the object.